# Multiple submissions from one page

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

am trying to allow a user to delete a certain image with is in a certain directory. I need them to first specify a directory and then the image which they want to delete.

I have been able to accomplish what I thought would be the hard part, of having their Gallery selection result in a drop-down populated only with the name of those images in their selected gallery.

My issue is that I cannot seem to get the submit button for my second form to trigger the if statement that will delete the files and remove the row from the table. I thought someone here might peruse my code and tell me what I am missing :(

thanks a ton!

```
    <form action ='' name="form1"  method='POST'  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Select Gallery: <select name="gal"  style="color:black;">
    <option value="" style="color:black;"><?php echo $gal; ?></option>
    <option value="graphicdesign/logos" style="color:black;">GD logos</option>
    <option value="graphicdesign/webdesign" style="color:black;">GD website design</option>
    <option value="graphicdesign/advertisements" style="color:black;">GD Advertisements</option>
    <option value="fineart/nature" style="color:black;">FA Nature</option>
    <option value="fineart/people" style="color:black;">FA People</option>
    <option value="fineart/landscapes" style="color:black;">FA Landscapes</option>
    <option value="photography/misc" style="color:black;">PG Misc</option>
    <option value="photography/nature" style="color:black;">PG Nature</option>
    <option value="photography/people" style="color:black;">PG People</option>
</select></p>
<input type="submit" value="Set Galery" style="color:black;"></p>
```

```
            <?php 

$connect = mysql_select_db("cynthie") or die("couln't find db on 2 :(");
$metaData = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `path_full`, `path_thumb`, `galId`  FROM `images`") or die("couln't find table :(");
$gal = $_POST['gal'];

                    if (isset($_POST['gal'])) 
                    {

                    echo '<form action ="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"><p>Select Image: <select name="toDelete" style="color:black;"><p><option style="color:black;">select img</option></p>';
                    while ($displayData = mysql_fetch_assoc($metaData)) 
                    {
                        $names = $displayData['name'];
                        $path_full = $displayData['path_full'];
                        $path_thumb = $displayData['path_thumb'];
                        $galDb = $displayData['galId'];

                        if ($galDb != $gal)
                        {}
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<p><option style="color:black;">'.$names.'</option></p>';
                        }

                    }

                    echo    '</select><p><input type="submit" value="Delete" style="color:black;"></p></form>';

     $connect = mysql_select_db("cynthie") or die("couln't find db on 4 :(");
     $delete = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM images WHERE name='$toDelete'") or die("couln't find table on line 81 :(");
    $toDelete = $_POST['toDelete'];     

                    if (isset($_POST['toDelete']))
                        {
                        unlink($path_full);
                        unlink($path_thumb);
                        mysql_query("DELETE FROM images WHERE `id`=$delete");
                        unset($delete);
                        echo '<p>removed!</p>';
                        }
                    else
                    {}

                        }




            ?>
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injections attacks! `"DELETE FROM images WHERE `id`=$delete"` where `$delete = $_POST['toDelete']`.

Comment: if it appears in a protected area, like an administration panel, should I be concerned? Would the solution be to pass write a function on separate page and call it here? Or to jump out to another page which handles the delete and then back?

Comment: Even then, you should worry, because then the only protection you'd have is the fact that the page isn't linked anywhere. The fact that people don't know the page exists doesn't mean they won't find it; that's security through obscurity. The solution is to properly escape parameters in your queries (or use prepared statements); if you don't know what that means, then you probably need to read up a bit more on SQL (see http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html for example)

Comment: I appreciate it it, and I will employ this, but in addition to what I posted here the beginning of this page starts a session preforms a check which will boot you to the login-screen. Really there should only be one person with access to this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `toDelete` check inside the `gal` check, so you need to have `$_POST['gal']` and `$_POST['toDelete']` being sent. I don't see `gal` in your second form, so just add `<input type="hidden" name="gal" value="{$_POST['gal']}" />`.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as Accepted - that way people will know at a glance that your problem has been solved.